# Can't use like operator in MS Access using c#

Tags: c#, ms-access

I am trying to search table using like operator however it always return 0 records. However if I use same query in SQL View in MS Access it works as expected. I am using following code:

```
string searchStr=search_text.Text;
if (search_text.Text.Length > 0)
{
    string ConnectString = "PROVIDER=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;DATA SOURCE=" +
        Server.MapPath("db\\fencing.mdb;");
    OleDbConnection objCon;
    OleDbCommand objCmd;
    DataTable DS = new DataTable();
    string strQuery = "select * from WorkOrders where subdivision like '*" 
        + searchStr + "*'";

    objCon = new OleDbConnection(ConnectString);
    OleDbDataAdapter d1 = new OleDbDataAdapter(strQuery, objCon);
    objCon.Open();
    d1.Fill(DS);
    int totalPages = 0;
    if (DS.Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        totalPages = DS.Rows.Count;
        GridView1.DataSource = DS;
        GridView1.DataBind();
        custPager.TotalPages = totalPages % GridView1.PageSize == 0 ?
            totalPages / GridView1.PageSize :
            totalPages / GridView1.PageSize + 1;

    }
    objCon.Close();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the * characters to %, which are what are used as wildcards in SQL queries.

Comment: Also, your query is completely vulnerable to SQL injection.  If you don't know what that is, look it up.

Comment: `%` is the wildcard used by the OleDb provider.

Comment: Even changing from * to % doesn't helps.

Comment: Can you provide a specific query that works when executed directly in Access works, but not through your C# code? (by "specific" I mean that you provide the exact query, keyword and all)

Answer (score 1):

i had use it with access its working well.
you have to try this also with % in place of *.

string SelectQry = @" select ID, Name from  Ledger where Name like '%" + Name + "%' ";